# How to let user edit his first name and last name in Parse?

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

Hi I am a beginner at programming, I have Facebook hooked up with parse. all i want to know is how to let the user edit his first name, last name.

I credit a textfields, so when the user clicks settings he can see, his first name in one editable textfield and his last name in another one. so the user can make changes in the app in a textfield, but how can i let him save it, I added button "SAVE" but i don't know how i can hook it up so "SAVE" button would actually change the user's first and last name.
I have this code

```
@IBOutlet weak var userLast: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var userFirst: UITextField!
```

// Show the current visitor's username

```
    if let pUserName = PFUser.currentUser()?["first_name"] as? String {
        self.userFirst.text = pUserName

        if let pUserName = PFUser.currentUser()?["last_name"] as? String {
            self.userLast.text = pUserName
```

Answer (score 0):

When the save button is tapped you basically do what you currently have in reverse. Currently you get the first and last names from the user and add them to the text fields. So now you would get the names from the text fields and set them into the current user. Then you can save the current user.

Comment: Can you please write in code how it would be reversed, Im very new to programming

Comment: I did this ----------

  @IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        
        if let updateObject = currentObject as PFObject? {
            
            // Update the existing parse object
            updateObject["first_name"] = userFirst.text
            updateObject["last_name"] = userLast.text
            
            // Save the data back to the server in a background task
            updateObject.saveEventually()  ------------------

but it gives me error on -------- if let updateObject = currentObject as PFObject? {

Comment: Should be using PFUser.currentUser()